# CRTP child defines type to be used by parent

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have a CRTP hierarchy, where the child defines a type to be used by the Parent, but that type has a callback in to the Parent:

```
template<template<class> class CALLBACK>
class Option1
{ 
};

template<class SUB>
class Parent
{
    using ThisClass = Parent<SUB>;
    
    typename SUB::template Sender<ThisClass> _osm;
};

class Child : public Parent<Child>
{
    using Sender = Option1;
};

int main()
{
    Child rm;
}
```

I thought I could use template template parameters to solve this but I still get compiler errors:

```
<source>:15:28: error: no member named 'Sender' in 'Child'
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Impossible. When the compiler reaches `public Parent<Child>`, it wants to know `SUB::Sender`, but the alias `using Sender = Option1` is not yet reached and `Child` is not completely defined. Pass `Option1` in a second `Parent` template parameter.

Comment: What does `Sender<ThisClass>` mean? `Sender` expects a template template parameter, but `ThisClass` is not a template.

Comment: @273K but `Option1` requires `Parent` as it's parameter type? Won't the same problem exist?

Comment: @Evg Only `Child` knows the type of `Sender`. However, `Sender` requires the type of `Parent` for use as a callback.

Comment: You can also pass this as a second template argument to Parent. That's often an easy choice.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it directly because `SUB` in `Parent` is an incomplete type, but you can use type traits technique and put `Sender` type into a separate helper struct:

```
template<template<class> class Callback>
class Option1 { 
};

class Child;

template<class>
struct GetSender;

template<>
struct GetSender<Child> {
    template<template<class> class Callback>
    using Type = Option1<Callback>;
};

template<class Sub>
class Parent {
    typename GetSender<Sub>::template Type<Parent> _osm;
};

class Child : public Parent<Child> {
};
```

This works because `GetSender` doesn't need a complete `Sub`.